# How to recolor all model's parts when using raycasting?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I have a `fanfare.reality` model in my `arView` from Reality Composer. I do raycast by `entity(at:location)` and enable the `ModelDebugOptionsComponent(visualizationMode: .lightingDiffuse)` of the objects hit, which make the appearance of objects turns grey. However, I found only the fanfare itself turns grey and the flag above the fanfare does not change at all.

[image]

I load the fanfare.reality by `LoadAsync()` and print the returned value as follows. The reason is that the flag, star and fanfare itself are divded into 3 `ModelEntity`. In RealityKit, raycast searches the entities with `CollisionComponent`.only can be added to entities that have `ModelComponent`.

[image]

Therefore, my question how can I turn the entire reality model grey (fanfare+flag+star) when I tap the model on screen(by raycast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Separate-parts-model approach

You can easily retrieve all 3 models. But you have to specify this whole long hierarchical path:

```
let scene = try! Experience.loadFanfare()

// Fanfare – .children[0].children[0]
let fanfare = scene.children[0] ..... children[0].children[0] as! ModelEntity
fanfare.model?.materials[0] = UnlitMaterial(color: .darkGray)
    
// Flag – .children[1].children[0]
let flag = scene.children[0] ..... children[1].children[0] as! ModelEntity
flag.model?.materials[0] = UnlitMaterial(color: .darkGray)

// Star – .children[2].children[0]
let star = scene.children[0] ..... children[2].children[0] as! ModelEntity
star.model?.materials[0] = UnlitMaterial(color: .darkGray)
```

I don't see much difference when retrieving model entities from `.rcproject`, `.reality` or `.usdz` files. According to the printed diagram, all three model-entities are located at the same level of hierarchy, they are offsprings of the same entity. The condition in the `if statement` can be set to its simplest form – if a ray hits a [collision shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60191009/reality-composer-custom-collision-between-entities-of-different-scenes/60192226#60192226) of `fanfare` or (`||`) `flag` or (`||`) `star`, then all three models must be recolored.

### Mono-model approach

The best solution for interacting with 3D models through raycasting is the ***mono-model approach***. A mono-model is a solid 3D object that does not have separate parts – all parts are combined into a whole model. Textures for mono-models are always [mapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170389/add-texture-to-some-part-of-3d-model/58182496#58182496) in UV editors. The mono-model can be made in 3D authoring apps like Maya or Blender.

---

P.S.

All seasoned AR developers know that *Wow! AR experience* isn't about code but rather about 3D content. You understand that there is no "miracle pill" for an easy solution if your 3D model consists of many parts. *Competently made AR model is 75% of success when working with code*.

Comment: Oh! The problem is that I have lots of reality models, e.g. `crown.reality`, `card.reality`, etc. I want to load and process them in a generic way. So I choose to use `LoadAsync(URL)` instead of `Experience.loadFanfare()`.

Furthermore, I only can retrieve the `modelEntity` hit by ray (one of `fanfare `, `flag`, `star`). According to your method, I have to find the parent (`scene`) of the hit `modelEntity`(e.g. fanfare) then retrieve other `modelEntity`(e.g. flag, star).

Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes. The method you mentioned works fine when the number of models is 1 or 2. However, If I have more than 3 `.reality` models and the user can place them any number of times in the `arView`. Firstly, I have to hardcode for each `.reality` model. For example, If the user places a `fanfare.reality`, I have to hardcode to get several `modelEntity` (`fanfare`, `flag`, `star`) of `fanfare.reality`.  If `card.reality`, get several `modelEntity` (`cover`, `bookmark`, etc) of `card.reality`. If `crown.reality`, get `head`, `body` of it. This is quite a lot of work if there are 10 or more models.

Comment: Therefore, the problem is that when the ray hits `flag` and I can not get the other `ModelEntity`(`fanfare`, `star`) in the same `.reality` model in advance, how can I retrieve the other `ModelEntity`(`fanfare`, `star`) by `flag` and make them grey? Is there a great solution?

Comment: Valuable advice